# When would you use a column name instead of * in a count?

Tags: sql, count

I understand why you use `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT col)`, but in which cases would you use simply `COUNT(col)`.  Wouldn't `COUNT(col)` return the same result as `COUNT(*)`?

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS OrdersFromCustomerID7 FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID=7;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersFromCustomerID7 FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID=7;
```

both result in

OrdersFromCustomerID7
4

in this W3 school [example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_count).

Comment: don't use w3 as a learning tool

Comment: You will notice a difference if `col` is `NULL`. That's not counted,  `COUNT(*)` will count every record.

Comment: IIRC COUNT(col) doesn't count NULL values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use **COUNT(Colomn)** It won't count **nulls**.

As opposed to **COUNT(*)** which will count **each row** individually no matter null or not.

Lets take this case:

```
ID   |  NAME
 1      John
 2      NULL
 3      Jonathan

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table -- return 3

SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM Table -- return 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(2),(NULL);

SELECT *
FROM @tbl

SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT_Asterisk
      ,COUNT(SomeValue) AS COUNT_SomeValue
FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

When you count a column that is not `NULL`, then the following produce the same results:

- `COUNT(*)`
- `COUNT(1)`
- `COUNT(column)`

There is often a small potential difference in performance.  The first two count *rows*.  The third actually requires reading the column value (at least in most databases).  Under some circumstances, this can require reading additional data to determine if the value is indeed not `NULL`.  This overhead is typically quite small in an aggregation query.

The first, using `*`, is the original way of counting rows.  The second is fine, although I prefer the first.  Why?  Because `COUNT(1)` = `COUNT(2)`, and I find that awkward.

Answer (score 1):

The results vary in cases where column values can be NULL. Both also vary when it comes to performance. You can refer to this article for more details [count-vs-countcol](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)